# Using MemoryFS file-like object with PIL Image

Tags: python, filesystems, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to open Image file from PyFileSystem MemoryFS using PIL, I tried to do that like this example and i got the error below:

```
from PIL import Image
from fs.memoryfs import MemoryFS

fs=MemoryFS()
fs.makedir("test")
out=fs.open("test/file.jpg",'wb')
out.write(someimagefile.read())
out.close()
in=fs.open("test/file.jpg",'rb')
im=Image.open(in) #error: cannot identify image file <IO wrapper for <MemoryFile in <MemoryFS> test/file.jpg>>
```

however if I don't use a directory (ex. `out=fs.open("file.jpg",'wb')`) It does work as expected.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I already get an error using the following line:

```
from fs.memoryfs import MemoryFS
```

Probably I don't have that library installed. Do you need this library? You can just open the image without opening it with MemoryFS:

```
im = Image.open("test/file.jpg")
```

Side note: I wouldn't use `in` as variable name, since it is also a Python keyword.